# Events are not fired from nested Accordion control

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Suppose we have Accordion control with several buttons placed in other Accordion control. Issue is in the fact that those button's events are not handled on server side. Example:

I have following code:

```
<form runat="server">
<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>
<ajax:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" Enabled="True" Visible="true">
    <Panes>
        <ajax:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane1" runat="server">
            <Header>
                header1 <asp:button id="ButtonH" runat="server" text="ButtonH" onclick="Button1_OnClick" />
            </Header>
            <Content>
                <ajax:Accordion ID="Accordion12" runat="server" Enabled="True">
                    <Panes>
                        <ajax:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane12" runat="server">
                            <Header>
                                header2 
                                <asp:button id="ButtonH2" runat="server" text="ButtonH2" onclick="Button1_OnClick" />
                            </Header>
                            <Content>
                                <asp:button id="ButtonContent" runat="server" text="Content" onclick="Button1_OnClick" />
                                content1</Content>
                        </ajax:AccordionPane>
                    </Panes>
                </ajax:Accordion>
            </Content>
        </ajax:AccordionPane>
    </Panes>
</ajax:Accordion>
</form>
```

Codebehind:

```
 protected void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    var button = (Button)sender;
 }
```

`Button1_OnClick` method is executed only on `ButtonH` click but not on `ButtonH2` nor `ButtonContent`clicks. Does anybody have any ideas what I miss?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this happen on every browser? I.e., is the issue browser-specific?

Comment: @Abel: This happens at least on IE 9 and FF 5.0, so seems like it is not browser-specific.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related but check yourself: http://forums.asp.net/t/1405543.aspx/1?ImageButton+onclick+event+is+not+fired+in+AccordionPane

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Thank you for solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Tim Schmelter I fixed this issue.

[Here is the forum post he referred to](http://forums.asp.net/p/1386290/2948060.aspx#2948060) that explains the changes that need to be done. A summary of what I found:

The Accordion.cs class needs to inherit from `INamingContainer` on line 46

```
public class Accordion : WebControl, INamingContainer`
```

as referred to in [this related ASP.NET post](http://forums.asp.net/p/1152731/1892385.aspx#1892385)

and the Accordion `ItemCommand` needs to have the `AccordionCommandEventArgs` defined in the event handler on line 68:

```
public event EventHandler<AccordionCommandEventArgs> ItemCommand;
//public event CommandEventHandler ItemCommand;
```

as referred to in [this codeplex post](http://www.codeplex.com/AjaxControlToolkit/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=16965)

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the `SuppressHeaderPostbacks="false"`. It worked for me.